# How to show horizontally data in rdlc report?

Tags: c#, vb.net, reportviewer, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I am using visual studio 2013 and access database. i want to display horizontally data in rdlc report as shown in image. 
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

width, height and orientation of a Report (.rdlc) depends on the two factors :

1. What page settings are applied on the report. We can set orientation to landscape by                  opening report.
   [image: Set Horizontal position or orientation]
2. Adding Some line of codes to define width, height and orientation.

Comment: It would be better to set margins and orientation of a report by setting it on Report Properties.